# vue js count down timer according to working hours

Tags: vue.js

i want to create a countdown timer. but i want to update the deadline by taking 9 hours (9 am to 6 pm) as a day. in this code its taking 24 hours a day

like if I put 18 hours in the tenure, the deadline will be calculated by adding 2 days with the startDate.
and if I put 20 hours in the tenure, the deadline will be calculated by adding 2 days and 2 hours with the startDate.

```js
    var application = new Vue({
     
      data:
        {
        countdownData: {
        startDateTime: null,
        startHour: 9,
        endHour:  18,
        tenure:  1,
        time: {
          total:  0,
          days: 0,
          hours:0,
          minutes:0,
          seconds:0,
        },
        deadline: null,
        paused: false,
        timeLeft: 0,
        timeInterval: null,
        countdownActive: false,
        offDays: 0,
      },
        },
    

filters: {
formatDate: function (value) {
  if (value) {
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 
'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' };
    return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  }
      return '';
    },
  },
        methods: {
    timeRemaining(endtime) {
      const t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.now();
      const seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      const minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      const hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      const days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return { total: t, days, hours, minutes, seconds };
    },
    runClock() {
      this.updateClock();
      this.countdownData.timeInterval = setInterval(this.updateClock, 1000);
    },
    updateClock() {
      const currentTime = new Date();
      const isWithinWorkingHours =
          currentTime.getHours() >= this.countdownData.startHour &&
          currentTime.getHours() < this.countdownData.endHour;

      if (isWithinWorkingHours) {
        this.countdownData.countdownActive = true;
        this.countdownData.time = this.timeRemaining(
            this.countdownData.deadline
        );
        if (this.countdownData.time.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(this.countdownData.timeInterval);
        }
      } else {
        this.stopClock();
        this.countdownData.countdownActive = false;
      }
    },
    pauseClock() {
      if (!this.countdownData.paused) {
        this.countdownData.paused = true;
        clearInterval(this.countdownData.timeInterval);
        this.countdownData.timeLeft = this.countdownData.time.total;
      }
    },
    resumeClock() {
      if (this.countdownData.paused) {
        this.countdownData.paused = false;
        this.countdownData.deadline = new Date(
            Date.now() + this.countdownData.timeLeft
        );
        this.runClock();
      }
    },
    handleInput() {
      this.stopClock();
      this.countdownData.deadline = this.calculateDeadline();
      this.runClock();
    },
    stopClock() {
      clearInterval(this.countdownData.timeInterval);
    },
    calculateDeadline() {
      if (this.countdownData.startDateTime) {
        const startDateTime = new Date(this.countdownData.startDateTime);
        const tenureInMillis = this.countdownData.tenure * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const offDaysInMillis = this.countdownData.offDays * 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const totalMillis = tenureInMillis - offDaysInMillis;
        return new Date(startDateTime.getTime() + totalMillis);
      }
      return null;
    },
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.stopClock();
  },
  mounted() {
    this.handleInput();
  },
        }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="startDateTimeInput">Enter Start Date and Time:</label>
          <input
              type="datetime-local"
              id="startDateTimeInput"
              v-model="countdownData.startDateTime"
              @input="handleInput"
              class="form-control"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="tenureInput">Enter Tenure (in hours):</label>
          <input
              type="number"
              id="tenureInput"
              v-model="countdownData.tenure"
              @input="handleInput"
              class="form-control"
              min="1"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="offDaysInput">Enter Off Days:</label>
          <input
              type="number"
              id="offDaysInput"
              v-model="countdownData.offDays"
              @input="handleInput"
              class="form-control"
              min="0"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="" v-if="countdownData.countdownActive">
      <div class="mx-auto" id="clockdiv">
    

<h2 class="text-center text-danger">{{ countdownData.time.hours }}: {{ countdownData.time.minutes }} :{{ countdownData.time.seconds }}</h2>

      </div>
 <div class="text-center">
    <p>Deadline: {{ countdownData.deadline | formatDate }}</p>
  </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" type="button" @click="pauseClock">Pause</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="resumeClock">Resume</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <p>The countdown is only active during the specified working hours.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: the problem is - deadline is showing after the office hours(9 am to 6 pm). it want move to next day(9 AM) when the deadline is after 6PM

Comment: for example.
`the project startDate is - 20/12/2023 9:00AM<br/>`
`tenure is - 18 hours`<br/>
`so the deadline will be - 21/12/2023 6:00PM`<br/>